# How do I code an IF statment within a string?

Tags: php, string, if-statement

I've tried every combination I could think of, but nothing is working.  How do I integrate an IF statement within a string?

This is the line I need integrated;

```
if ($row['SL'] == 'Yes') {echo '<li class=\"sl\">Short Sale</li>' ;}
```

This is what I tried;

```
elseif ($row['X'] == 'sold') { echo "
    <li id=\"price\"> $ {$row['SP$']}</li>
 " .
    { if ($row['SL'] == 'Yes') {echo '<li class=\"sl\">Short Sale</li>' ;} }
 . "
    <li>Days on Market: {$row['DOM']}</li>;
 }
```

Comment: Do you get any errors? If no, just split it up into three different strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to break it up:

```
elseif ($row['X'] == 'sold') { 
    echo "<li id=\"price\"> $ {$row['SP$']}</li>";

    if ($row['SL'] == 'Yes') {
        echo '<li class=\"sl\">Short Sale</li>';
    }

    echo "<li>Days on Market: {$row['DOM']}</li>;
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a ternary operator:

```
elseif ($row['X'] == 'sold') { echo "
    <li id=\"price\"> $ {$row['SP$']}</li>
 " . ($row['SL'] == 'Yes') ? '<li class="sl">Short Sale</li>' : ''
 . "
    <li>Days on Market: {$row['DOM']}</li>";
 }
```

Comment: This echoed the "Short Sale" only, ignoring all other list-items.  I coded it as followd; <li></li>
" . ($row['SL'] == 'Yes') ? '<li class="sl">Short Sale</li>' : '' . " <li></li>

Answer (score 0):

You don't. You output the first half the string, then fully stop that statement, then evaluate your `if`, then output the rest of the string.

```
...
elseif ($row['X'] == 'sold') {
  echo "<li id=\"price\"> $ {$row['SP$']}</li>";
  if ($row['SL'] == 'Yes') {
    echo '<li class=\"sl\">Short Sale</li>'
  }
  echo "<li>Days on Market: {$row['DOM']}</li>";
 }
```

You can't "embed" an `if` statement in a string, firstly because that's not syntactically valid, but even if it was, `if` statements don't resolve to a value in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called [Ternary Operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) or Shorthand If/Else:

```
( condition ? true result : false result )
```

Example:

```
echo "<li id=\"price\">{$row['SP']}</li>" . ( $row['SL'] == 'Yes' ? '<li class="sl">Short Sale</li>' : '' ) . "<li>Days on Market: {$row['DOM']}</li>";
```

The above example is the same as:

```
echo "<li id=\"price\">{$row['SP']}</li>";
if ( $row['SL'] == 'Yes' ) echo '<li class="sl">Short Sale</li>';
else echo '';
echo "<li>Days on Market: {$row['DOM']}</li>";
```

You can "stack" ternary expressions so the complete example will look like:

```
echo 
    $row['X'] == 'sold' 
        ? "<li id=\"price\">{$row['SP']}</li>" .
          ( $row['SL'] == 'Yes' ? '<li class="sl">Short Sale</li>' : '' ) .
          "<li>Days on Market: {$row['DOM']}</li>" 
        : '';
```

**important**: you cannot build a ternary operator without else statement.